# How to remove Access forbidden! Error 403 from xampp 5.6

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have tried all solutions available online for e.g.

```
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

I have added above lines in httpd-xampp.conf but nothing happen. Please Help!!

Comment: Those two directives are from different versions, use the latter if you use 2.4, and only that one.

Comment: @ezra-s yes, you are right. Thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 1):

At last, I found an answer -:

Try this "**Require all granted**"

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "D:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Open httpd-vhosts.conf file and in the bottom of the file change it

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot “E:/xampp/htdocs/”
ServerName localhost
<Directory E:/xampp/htdocs/>.
Require all granted 
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>



Here E:/xampp is my project workspace, you can change it as per your settings and Second Change is

Now Open httpd-xampp.conf file and in the bottom of the file change it

#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))”>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

NOTE : Make sure u  backup files ( httpd-xampp.conf ) and ( httpd-vhosts.conf ) , Both Files are located in Drive:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
```

Comment: Actually, I don't have LocationMatch tag in my httpd-xampp.conf file.

Comment: can you please search this file.... with the help of search box at the right top corner of your window

Comment: D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra path of my httpd-xampp.conf file

Comment: What if I don't have LocationMatch tag in my httpd-xampp.conf. As I told you I don't have this tag in my conf file. I have also added this tag in file but nothing happened.

Comment: then please mention this tag

Comment: In xampp 5.6, there is not any locationmatch tag. it needs to add only "required all granted", if it "required local".